# Android app doesn't fetch data from server when connected to different network

Tags: android

I am stuck in a problem.I have made a code to fetch data from server.When I run,it only runs on that network where I run it first time.When I try to run my app from other network it gives me volley timeout error.I have changed urls according to desired networks but didn't work.It only fetches the data successfully only on one network and in other networks it gives volley timeout error.I have used JSON to fetch from the Server.Below is my Code:

```
 Button Show;
TextView Result;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
String URL="http://192.168.0.103/fetchdata.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Show=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Show);
    Result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    Show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            JsonObjectRequest jsonobjectrequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                    try{
                        JSONArray signin=response.getJSONArray("signin");
                        for (int i=0;i<signin.length();i++)
                        {

                            JSONObject signin1=signin.getJSONObject(i);

                            String Username=signin1.getString("username");
                            String Password=signin1.getString("password");
                            String Email=signin1.getString("email");


                            Result.append(Username+" "+Email+" "+Password+ "\n");
                        }

                        Result.append("===\n");
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                          e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            requestQueue.add(jsonobjectrequest);
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can access your server from other networks?
According to the URL you provided in your example it seems that you are targeting a local server. So if you're on a different network you may not be able to access it. That could be why your request timeout.

Comment: I have extracted the data from the webserver only from One network.I didn't use local db.When I want to access from different network I changes  the URL according to that network But it didn't works.It only works for the network where I run my app first time.

Comment: What I mean is 192.168.0.103 is an IP for a local network. To access it the device running your app needs to be on the same network as the server. If you change the network (connect to an other WiFi network for example) on your device, you'll not be able to reach the server as it's not on this network. That why you can get the data only when you connect to a specific network (the one the server is connected to).

Comment: Probably that might be the problem..So what should I do to enable it from every wifi?

Comment: You need your server to have a public IP (means to be accessible from Internet) and then you target this IP instead of your local one.
Search something like "local server accessible from web" in Google to see how to achieve that.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: Not yet.But still trying...